# Skype for Business UCWA oauth problems, error 401 when try create ucwa applications

Tags: oauth, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper, ucwa

I have error "401 Unauthorized" when try create application by request:

> POST //pool-lync-fe02.****.net/ucwa/v1/applications HTTP 1.1

Two another requests is correct and returns "OK":

> POST https://pool-lync-fe02.****.net/WebTicket/oauthtoken and
>
> GET
>   //pool-lync-fe02.****/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root/oauth/user?originalDomain=moscow.alfaintra.net

After AutodiscoverService i have this(lines have different sites!):

> self":{"href":"//pool-lync-fe02.****.net/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root/oauth/user
>
> applications":{"href":"//webext.****.ru/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications
>
> xframe":{"href":"//webext.****.ru/Autodiscover/XFrame/XFrame.html

Please, help. Why token failed when get created ucwa apps?

Comment: Tokens are only valid for the origin from which they are issued so your .net token would be invalid for .ru.

Comment: Thank you! Question like i post to Ganesh: But why AutodiscoverService return lines in answer wirh different servers? It's error in topology or configuration? Where i can see this parameters of AutodiscoverService and change this?

Answer (score 1):

Each time when you target a different host, in your case webext.***.ru vs pool-lync-fe..., you need to get a new oauth token where the audience is pointing to the host of the HTTP request you are sending it to.

Ganesh

Comment: Thank you! But why AutodiscoverService return lines in answer wirh different servers? It's error in topology or configuration? Where i can see this parameters of AutodiscoverService and change this?

Comment: There can be many front-end servers in the topology (typically where AutoDiscoverService exists) and you may need to authenticate to one in order to get details for the next server.  What is a bigger problem is that you need to recognize that the origin is different between your AutoDiscoverService and applications href and construct a URL.  You can construct the URL using the previous user href and replace the origin with what is found in application/xframe's href.